# Intuition behind mild solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, intuition

In this question, there is a nice intuitive explanation, why one uses weak solutions and what the intuition is behind the weak solutions: [intuition behind weak solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149747/intuition-behind-weak-solution)

Is there a similar explanation for mild solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Best,

Luke

Answer (score 0):

See [Is a mild solution the same thing as a weak solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708407/is-a-mild-solution-the-same-thing-as-a-weak-solution) , in which an example is given where a weak solution and mild solution for a particular problem coincide.

Mild solutions are weak solutions in the sense that they are not necessarily classical solutions.  They are just a different way of getting a potential classical solution, or a substitute for a classical solution if none exist.

Comment: There are probably also mild solutions, which are not weak solutions (I don't know an example, but otherwise there would only be one concept, I suppose). What is the difference of the two, if mild and weak solutions don't coincide?

Comment: It depends on what problem you're working on.  Intuitively, it's a technicality.  Probably the most common problem is uniqueness.  E.g. $L^\infty$ weak solutions to the Navier--Stokes equations are nonunique but $L^\infty$ mild solutions are unique.  In terms of definitions, mild solutions are solutions to integral equations, whereas weak solutions are distribution solutions to differential equations.